# Increase column value by X every T seconds

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to increase (*or* generally tamper with) a database column value (*e.g. time_passed*) every set amount of time.

How do I address this issue? Should I approach this server side or database side?

My app is using Express, Socket.IO and I am using a MySQL database.

Comment: What did you try so far? You could use `setInterval` but without any code it's hard to tell you something.

Comment: If you store a timestamp, then you always know how many 'set amount of times' have passed since the timestamp. So why then would you need to do this?

Comment: @MicheleMarcucci I tried an update query. But I do not know how to do this every X time, or where I should do it, server or db side(if that's an option)?

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't quite get what you mean

Comment: Are Cron jobs an option?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Seems interesting, but I am not familiar with that, have you used it?

Comment: @Valamorde I have used it for PHP scripts, I've never used node.js. Basically for PHP you can make it run a script every time you want it to, you can be very specific with the timing like every 5 minutes, every 1 day, every week, etc. I'm pretty sure you can do it with node.js too.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I'll try it and report back!

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton works perfectly, now how do i address the DB part? Keep using update queries or is there a better way?

Comment: @Valamorde Well you are just running a script every _x_ time, so I would just do it the way you would do it if you were just adding that script to a page to be loaded by a user tbh. Update queries are the way to go probably.

Comment: As others have noted, this is an odd way of doing it. Instead of a `time_passed` field, have a `time_started` field. Store a Unix timestamp and you can always just subtract that value from the current timestamp to get the time elapsed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest using Cron jobs for this.

> The software utility Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like
>   computer operating systems. People who set up and maintain software
>   environments use cron to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to
>   run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals. It typically
>   automates system maintenance or administration—though its
>   general-purpose nature makes it useful
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

You can set up a Cron job to automatically run a script periodically, which you can do database maintenance with.

Cron is driven by a crontab (cron table) file, a configuration file that specifies shell commands to run periodically on a given schedule. Users can have their own individual crontab files and often there is a system-wide crontab file (usually in /etc or a subdirectory of /etc) that only system administrators can edit.

Each line of a crontab file represents a job, and looks like this:

```
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
# │ │ │ │ │                                       7 is also Sunday on some systems)
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * *  command to execute
```

The following example would run the script at `/home/oracle/scripts/export_dump.sh` every Saturday at 11:45 PM.

```
45 23 * * 6 /home/oracle/scripts/export_dump.sh
```

Comment: Cron's the wrong approach here, IMO. If the cron fails once, the underlying data will now be permanently and undetectably *wrong*.

Comment: I like the idea behind Cron, it seems like the easiest way to go, but ceejayoz's comment got me thinking about the validity of my data. In which cases would Cron fail?

Comment: An error in the script, a database outage, a server outage, network troubles, someone disables the script for a few minutes for debugging, etc. are all possible.

Comment: A solution to that would have it automatically send an email from the script with a status report. If you don't get the email, your data will be wrong and you can manually runnthe script yourself. @Valamorde

Comment: Thoughts on that @ceejayoz?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I think that's really over-complicating something that has a simple solution.

Comment: @ceejayoz I guess agree to disagree. I don't think having a script send an email is very complicated at all.

Comment: I simply used `cron` to call the functions every X seconds, and @strawberry 's answer to ensure my data is valid. However since both answers helped me I think it's unfair to select only one.

Comment: @Valamorde You should select the one that _helped the most_ in your case. Whichever one that is, is really up to you. Consider if one answer would be impossible without another perhaps? I don't really know how you would choose.

Comment: I feel bad to leave any out, your answer taught me how to call a function every set amount of time and strawberry's (with ceejayoz's addition) taught me how to ensure the validity of my data.

Comment: @Valamorde Well technically IMO your question is more asking how to do something every set amount of time, but that's up to you to decide your actual question. Of course, no matter which answer you choose, you can still give the other one an upvote as well so that all authors get a little bit of rep for it if you haven't already. If multiple answers help me I typically choose the answer in which the author has a lower reputation level, it helps them out a little bit more.

Comment: @Valamorde think you've taken a tragically wrong direction here (and it's not even my downvote)

Comment: @ceejayoz I took both answers into consideration and applied both! What's wrong with that? Even if I restart my server later on it catches up! So far, so good IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say I store a timestamp at midnight (00:00:00), and I'm interested in increasing a column value (say 100) by 1 every 10 seconds. So, in reality I don't need to *do* anything else. After 60 seconds, I know that the new value is simply:

```
100 + (1 x ((60-0)/10)) = 106
```

Comment: I don't need the calculation of the actual value, just the programmatically correct way to increase a column value every (say) 10 seconds by (say) 5 in node.js. Maybe my question was not clear enough, should I edit it?

Comment: @Valamorde You can accomplish that goal in this way, though. If you want to it to go up by five every ten seconds, use modulus (`diff % 10`) and then multiply that by five. This will ensure the answer is *always* correct, even if your server goes down or something.

Comment: @ceejayoz What you are suggesting is very interesting! Any chance you could write that in an answer with a snippet example?

Comment: @Valamorde IMO, my comment is just a minor modification to this answer, and it deserves the credit instead. The addition of the modulus just makes it granular so you don't have fractional increases.

Comment: @ceejayoz agreed but how and when does one call said functionality? Don't I need to call it every X seconds, minutes or whatever? Am I missing something here?

Comment: You'd run that calculation when you need the value. If you're displaying it to the user, you'd just run it as part of that process.